# What does "with your horns up" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

It’s in your nature to read self-help books like this **with your horns up**,
ready to pounce on any idea you think is flawed.
It’s easy to be a cynic. It requires no energy to be skeptical or
negative.

I tried to search this on dictionary and google, but no accurate result found.

Comment: *Horns up* does appear in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Horns+up) but it doesn't fit. It's a good idea to **include your own research in your question,** even -- especially -- if it was fruitless.

Answer (score 2):

**with one's horns up** = in an aggressive or beligerent mood, ready to attack.

This has nothing to do with the Devil. It is figurative and based upon the attack method of a bull or other horned animal.

> I saw a huge gaur[1] rushing out of a thick bamboo bush to attack us. It was less than 10 meters from me and I did not have time to raise my gun. Head down, **horns up**, he attacked in a lightning rush forward, his huge feet stomping the ground like thunder. *Brushing the World Famous: The Story of My Life by Hanh Nguyen*

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaur

> The most famous popular gesture of recent years, the V for Victory sign popularized by Sir Winston Churchill, seems to be a horns-up sign, implying the power of a horned animal. *Man, Myth & Magic: An Illustrated Encyclopedia of the Supernatural, Volume 8 (1970)*

Answer (score -1):

Given the rest of the sentence, I believe that it is referencing "bad" tendencies of someone. Sort of like jumping in and assuming the worst / listening to the devil on your shoulder.